# Writing abstract classes while using Freezed

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, json-serializable

I can't seem to understand how to make abstract classes and their subclasses work properly with Freezed. Specifically, I need to define an abstract super-class with some to-override getters; the subclasses will need to override the getters, while exploiting freezed to generate their boilerplate code.

I do understand what the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#mixins-and-interfaces-for-individual-classes-for-union-types) suggests, but I do need more.

I created [a repo](https://github.com/lucavenir/freezed_problems) to show off what I need, in case you want to cut to the chase. All I need are [these tests](https://github.com/lucavenir/freezed_problems/blob/main/test/this_test.dart) to pass and work as intended.

I need a clean, readable and maintainable way to do this.

### Scenario

In the repo you'll find a small reproduction case:

- A `Base` abstract class;
- A class `A`, which extends the `Base` class (I wanted to simplify things, but I do have more subclasses in my real use case, say `X`, `Y`, `Z`, etc.);
- `A` needs to be implemented with Freezed, with JSON serialization / deserialization;

Recap: `Base` is there to have write common ground between `A`, `X`, `Y` and `Z`; as mentioned above, Freezed is a must-have for these subclasses.

### Goal

My goal is to exploit composition.

Let a class `B` have a `Base get myValue` getter, with Freezed. Unsurprisingly, I want to interact with this value by accessing its `copyWith` method (or others, like `toJson`), but this gets complicated quite fast (see Problem 1).

Again, read the tests for the desired outcome.

### Problem 1

Implementing what I've described above, while it makes sense, is no easy task (to my understanding).

For example, the following:

```dart
abstract class Base {
  const Base();

  Function copyWith();
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  String get id;
}
```

won't work because the subclasses will feel ambiguity onto which superclass method to use (error [here](https://github.com/lucavenir/freezed_problems/blob/5afbea3292ac990c859b665296072ed79a0b4a8c/lib/models/a.dart#L9)): should it use the one generated by `@freezed`, or the abstract one? That's a compile-time error.

I have no clue how to properly write a contract while exploiting Freezed.

### Problem 2

At first, `build_runner` rightfully complains as it can't generate the `fromJson` method onto `B` because `Base` has no `@JsonSerializable` method.

This would imply implementing a converter manually: I did so, but this gets old quickly. This implies to re-write the converter for each new subclass created and raise an exception for a subclass that isn't handled, yet (that's a strong code smell).

Such atrocity is found in [this file](https://github.com/lucavenir/freezed_problems/blob/main/lib/models/base.dart).

How can achieve this in a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of work and research, I managed to get out of this mess.

1. I had to drop `freezed` for now (I'll just keep it for the union type system);
2. Implementing this by hand is out of the question, obviously;
3. I used this package: [dart_mappable](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_mappable#polymorphism-and-discriminators), that does *exactly* what I've asked above.

I'll post here a quick pseudocode implementation achievable with `dart_mappable`:

```dart
@MappableClass()
abstract class MyBase with MyBaseMappable {
  const MyBase(this.id);
  final String id;
}

@MappableClass()
class A extends MyBase with AMappable {
  const A(super.id);
}

@MappableClass()
class B with BMappable {
  const B(this.value);
  final MyBase value;
}


void main() {
  const a = A('hello');
  const b = B(a);
  print(b.value.copyWith(id: "lol"));  // Yes!
}
```

This requires v2 of `dart_mappable` to work, which is currently in a pre-release state.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem likely stems from `Base` defining an empty `copyWith`

Freezed doesn't implement `copyWith` as a method, but as a getter that returns a function (or callable object). That's necessary for `copyWith(foo: null)` support, but is incompatible with your interface.

*Extending* `Base` could also be an issue. Freezed doesn't support inheritance too well because of language limitations. You're probably better off with implementing `Base` or making it a mixin.

All in all, you could do:

```dart
mixin Base {
  int get id;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}

@freezed
class A with _$A, Base {
  const A._();

  factory A({
    required int id;
  }) = _A;
  
  factory A.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Remi!! At the end of the day, all I need is a way to access Freezed' generated methods from a common interface, plus a few common getters that every subclass needs to implement. I'll try this Mixin and see if I can get away with it.

Comment: No, unluckily this isn't working. Please check my repo again (I've just pushed these suggestions) and see that: (1) I still have to implement a `BaseConverter`, which is another smell, or else `B` won't generate its code; and (2) something breaks up in the generation of class `A` as `a.freezed.dart` contains this error: `The method 'copyWith' isn't defined for the type '<unknown>'`.

Maybe you wanted to write `class A with _$A, Base` ?

Comment: Well `Base` does not have a `fromJson`, so you can't magically decode it. If you don't want the JsonConverter, feel free to add a `fromJson` to `Base`

Comment: Furthermore, not having `copyWith` as a getter on the mixin is still an open problem for me, I can't get out from that.

Comment: Hi again and thanks again for the help! I realize that `Base` hasn't a `fromJson`, my goal was to trigger its subclasses, but... that's impossible to make happen! That's a flaw in my reasoning. `B.fromJson` has no way to know if it should trigger `A.fromJson` or any other `X.fromJson` that subclass `Base`. So a custom `BaseConverter` must be implemented, there's no escaping that. After even more reasoning, I came to realize that this problem just isn't solvable with Freezed and that I must implement everything by hand. I'll help myself with Freezed in other contexts.

Comment: Specifically, (1) I can't solve the `copyWith` abstract method problem and (2) solving the aforementioned problem by introducing a `key` property messes up the solution you've found (`toJson` isn't really customizable because the converter will cass that method onto a `_$_A` type, see repo).
If Dart had dataclasses I'd just make `Base` an abstract dataclass and that would be it. Sad.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your help, I can't mark your answer as accepted as I can't tell my problems are exactly "solved". I'll wait for metaprogramming, then.